# Redirecionamento de URL http

Tags: apache, redirecionamento-de-url, httpd

Estou tentando fazer um redirecionamento de url, mas não está funcionando, alguém poderia me dizer o que está de errado?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/teste(.*)$ // verifica se tem /teste em alguma url
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^/parcerias/teste.html?utm_source=teste&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=parcerias  [R=302,L] // envia para está url
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Isto `%{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/teste(.*)$` verifica se tem `/test` na QUERY_sTRING, algo como `http://localhost/foo/bar?foo=/test`, é isso mesmo o que deseja? Agora se o objetivo é chegar na URL isto esta errado.

Comment: Eu desejo http://localhost/teste < verificar isso, depois da url base do site verificar se tem o valor teste.

Comment: Como eu faria para pegar o valor depois da url base e substituir?

Comment: Então QUERY_STRING não faz sentido, porque isso verifica o conteudo da querystring como `?foo=bar` e não do PATH.

Comment: Estou criando uma resposta.

Comment: Ah sim, parece que entendi o que vc quer dizer, ok estou aguardando

Comment: Postei uma resposta, mas não tenho certeza do que você deseja, testa o código e se não funcionar explique qual o objetivo para que eu possa editar a resposta dentro de sua necessidade.

Comment: Ele joga um valor antes da url, saberia o pq disso? `%5e/parcerias`

Comment: Gustavo editei a resposta, provavelmente o sinal de `^` na frente de `^/parcerias/teste.html` esta errado, este sinal é para regex, e ali não é regex é o caminho de destino apenas, então remova-o,

Comment: Opa, deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto `%{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/teste(.*)$` verifica se tem `/test` na **`QUERY_STRING`**, algo como `http://localhost/foo/bar?foo=/test`, é isso mesmo o que deseja? Agora se o objetivo é chegar na URL isto esta errado.

Outro detalhe, provavelmente o sinal de `^` na frente de `^/parcerias/teste.html` esta errado, este sinal é para regex, e ali não é regex é o caminho de destino apenas, então remova-o, deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /parcerias/teste.html
```

Creio que o quer seja o `REQUEST_URI` para verificar o *PATH* (caminho na URL):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/teste(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /parcerias/teste.html?utm_source=teste&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=parcerias [R=302,L]
```

Ou simplesmente aplicar no `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/teste(.*)$ ^/parcerias/teste.html?utm_source=teste&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=parcerias [R=302,L]
```

Claro que isto provavelmente vai causar um loop, já que a URL redirecionada também tem `/teste` em `/parcerias/teste.html`, provavelmente você quer o contrário, impedir o redirecionamento se já estiver em uma URL com `/teste`, então o que você deseja é uma condição de não contêm `/teste`, neste caso basta usar o sinal de `!`, assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/teste(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /parcerias/teste.html?utm_source=teste&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=parcerias [R=302,L]
```